# Deleting a data from a database with delete method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

so I am trying to delete an item from database using a button to call a delete function. everything works as they should and I can see the calling delete API log in the console however req.body is undefined I was wondering what am I doing wrong here.

here is the react part

```
export default function ProductPage({ items, adminToken }) {
  const deleteItem = async (itemId) => {
    const res = await fetch("/api/database/additems", {
      method: "delete",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(itemId),
    });
    const resResult = await res.json();
    console.log(resResult);
  };

  if (adminToken) {
    return (
      <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col bg-slate-200">
        <Header />
        this is the product page
        <div className="flex flex-wrap ml-16">
          {items.map((item) => (
            <div key={item._id}>
              <Link
                href={{
                  pathname: "products/[id]",
                  query: { id: `${item._id}` },
                }}
              >
                <a> item page</a>
              </Link>
              <button onClick={() => deleteItem(item._id)}>
                Delete this item
              </button>
```

and here is the API code

```
apiRouter.delete((req, res) => {
  console.log("calling delete API");
  console.log(req.body);

  res.redirect("/products");
});
```

I have not implemented the deleting part yet since I can not get the body which contains the item  unique id in the database.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` requires the body to have a `data` parameter.
So you'll need your request to be

```
const res = await fetch("/api/database/additems", {
  method: "delete",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({ data: itemId }),
});
```

Comment: still getting undefined when logging req.body